PowerBI / DAX different dates cumulative on one chart
i can't manage it on my own for 2 days.
I've got 3 tables:
One-off Expenditures:



Title
date
Amount




x
03.07.2024
10000


y
06.08.2024
10000


z
05.09.2024
20000



Weekly cash balance:



date
Amount




02.09.2024
5000


09.09.2024
25000



and calendar table
I'd like to create a graph as below showing:

cash balance on each week date from cash balance table
cumulative value of one-off expenditure from a date (01.08.2024) till the date from point 1

I wrote dax formulas and i'm able to present that on two graphs however when joining the data, either the cumulative one stop cumulating or it cumulates ignoring the dates
The result i'd like to obtain is a graph with:
02.09.2024 -  5.000 - 10.000
09.09.2024 - 25.000 - 30.000


Update/Edit your question to include the DAX formulas you have tried.

you can try to create two columns.
Column =
VAR _date =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[date] <= EARLIER ( 'Weekly cash balance'[date] ) ),
        'Table'[date]
    )
RETURN
    MAXX ( FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[date] = _date ), 'Table'[Amount] )

Column 2=
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        'Weekly cash balance',
        'Weekly cash balance'[date] <= EARLIER ( 'Weekly cash balance'[date] )
    ),
    'Weekly cash balance'[Column]
)



Hi, thanks for the comment. Adding first column returns 'a single value for column 'Weekly cash balance'[date] in table 'Weekly cash balance' cannot be determined' error :(

have you created relationship between these two tables? If you did, pls delete it.
